# Polymer querySelector can't find element in dom-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, polymer

#### Goal:

I'm trying to select a div inside a `dom-repeat` element.

The code below contains the div I want to select. `id="med[[index]]"`

#### Code:

```
<div class="card">
    <h1>Medicijn overzicht:</h1>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{employees}}">
        <div class="inner-card" id="[[index]]">
        <div><span><b>{{item.first}}</b></span> <span>{{item.last}}</span>mg<br><span>{{item.stuks}}</span> stuks</div>
        <div id="med[[index]]" style="display:none"><br><br><br><br><br>Goed verhaal</div>
        </div>
    </template>
</div>
```

#### Problem:

The goal here is to have the div expand when the parent gets clicked, but the querySelect seems to be unable to find the element when it is called from within the click function. When preforming this search at the top of the function with a static name it finds it just fine.

```
            attached:function(){
            this.async(function() {
                var cards = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelectorAll(".inner-card");
                var test = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector("#med0"); //Finds the element
                console.log(test);  // This is fine
                console.log("cards",cards);
                $(cards).click(function(evt){
                    var target= evt.currentTarget;
                    var tindex = target.id;
                    var targetDiv = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector("#med"+tindex); //Doesn't find it.
                    console.log("#med"+tindex)
                    console.log(targetDiv);
                    $(targetDiv).slideDown("slow");
                    console.log("trigger"+tindex);
                });
            });
       }
```

It might just be me misunderstanding how this works, I'm very new to this.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reference to `this.root` within click-handler is different than the one referenced above it. `root` probably does not exist within the `this` context of the click-handler—it certainly is not the same as the `this.root` above, since that `this` is referring to the global `this`.

You might want to save `this` or `this.root` for use within the click handler:

```
this.async(function() {
   var cards = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelectorAll(".inner-card");
   var test = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector("#med0");
   var root_root=this.root; // **ADD THIS**
   $(cards).click(function(evt){
      var target= evt.currentTarget;
      var tindex = target.id;
      var targetDiv = Polymer.dom(root_root).querySelector("#med"+tindex); // **CHANGE THIS**
      $(targetDiv).slideDown("slow");
      console.log("trigger"+tindex);
   });
});
```

Alternatively, if you can use ES6's arrow functions, you can fix this easier by simply converting the click handler to an arrow function,

```
$(cards).click((evt) => { …
```

This will use the `this` from the surrounding context of the arrow-function.

Comment: This solved my issue, also going to look into the arrow functions. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to add `.bind(this)` after end of function. I am using it in old projects, where ES6 can't be used. Using `.bind(this)` seems more 'cleaner'

In your case:

```
     $(cards).click(function(evt){
            var target= evt.currentTarget;
            var tindex = target.id;
            var targetDiv = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector("#med"+tindex); //Doesn't find it.
            console.log("#med"+tindex)
            console.log(targetDiv);
            $(targetDiv).slideDown("slow");
            console.log("trigger"+tindex);
     }.bind(this));
```